# Best way to connect microcontroller, sensor and LED

Tags: microcontroller, led, sensor

I'm trying to read output from a sensor and at the same time drive some indicator LEDs. The 3 pins are configured as input on the MCU and output on the sensor. Both the MCU and the Sensor are at 3.3V. 100k resistor serves as a pull-down resistor and 220 ohms serves as a current limiting resistor. **Am I doing this right? (See image)**
[image]

**Edit 1** :Minor correction on the image to connect the pull down for all lines as suggested

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the "Sinking Capability" specification in the datasheet will be referring to the MCU operating as an output driving low [*], there doesn't appear to be anything immediately wrong with that circuit if you redraw it correctly.

<strike>By drawing it correctly I presume you meant to connect one LED/pull-down to each line - you have connected two to the same line and none to the bottom</strike>. As a side note, while the way you have drawn the wire connections is correctly to one of the two standards, it tends to be easier to use the dot-cross style (a dot shows wires connected, and if they cross over they are unconnected) as that means you don't have to draw the little arcs to jump wires over.

You will only get ~\$5\space\mathrm{mA}\$ flowing through the LEDs when the sensor is outputting high. If you want the 10mA you have written on your schematic you would need to decrease the resistor value to \$120\space\Omega\$.

---

[*] The inputs are typically "High Impedance" which means they will sink virtually no current.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! Assuming I change the value of the resistor to 120 ohms, what will be the value of current through the input pins of the microcontroller when the sensor is outputting high? The current in the led path will be 10mA.

Comment: @AGM the microcontroller will be an input which means it will neither source nor sink current - virtually no current will flow in to it (talking \$\mu\mathrm{A}\$'s). It is the sensor output which is driving the LED.

Comment: My bad, you're right. So it will be the voltage level which help the microcontroller decide if it is a logic 0 or 1. Thanks! As per the MCU digital pin characteristics, minimum High level input voltage is 0.7Vdd(Vdd = 3.3V). So I should make sure the pin gets a minimum of 2.3V.